# VS 2017 & 2019 cannot find the WinRT header files, even on a fresh solution

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, include, c++-winrt

So I'm trying to update a Win32 application to UWP using a "Windows Application Packaging Project", I'm hitting filesystem issues, which I expected and am trying to resolve them. In order to do this, I need access to the WinRT libraries so that I can deal with UWP paths to get at my assets and resources.

I installed the C++/WinRT VSIX extension and added the NuGet package to my solution. I was assuming [from what i read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt#visual-studio-support-for-cwinrt-xaml-the-vsix-extension-and-the-nuget-package) that would be all I needed to do to access the header files. **However the compiler apparently cannot find the header files for WinRT and it's namespaces**, as I get messages saying `cannot open source file "winrt/Windows.Storage.h` and I can't use the `Windows::Storage::StorageFolder` calls I apparently need to get my file system code to work. Despite my best efforts to work out what include paths I'm missing, nothing has worked, so I tried a different tactic.

In the same solution I created a "DirectX 12 App (Universal Windows)" thinking that i may have been going down the wrong route and opted to see if i could re-implement my front end as a straight UWP app without the legacy win32. This fresh project seems to have the right includes as the `using` directives work for the `Windows.*` namespaces it uses, and it compiles. Despite this, i can't work out what it's doing to get access namespaces similar to the ones I need, so i can't reverse engineer it to get my original project working. However, I am sceptical if this is using the same libraries, as this project type was available since before I installed the C++/WinRT VSIX extension, and WinRT is not mentioned anywhere.

In order to go back to basics, I created a fresh solution with a "Windows Desktop Application (C++/WinRT)" as i know this uses the runtime I'm after, and it should be clean (as opposed to my long-used solution with tons of projects and configurations) so i can see the options it's using for me to replicate and access the tools i need. However, freshly created, the project will not compile and it cites exactly the same reason as my original solution and project about not being able to find the WinRT headers. This baffled me, so i assumed that it was some other config I'd done globally to VS2017.

To isolate this, I installed VS2019 and added the extension to it, thinking "new environment, no config screwups". But again a freshly created "Windows Desktop Application (C++/WinRT)" project would not build and it could not find the header files.

The autogenerated pch.h contains the following

```
//it can't find anything starting with "winrt/"
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.System.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.h>
//but it finds this one totally fine
#include <Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting.DesktopWindowXamlSource.h>
```

So this is happening in both old and new solution files, and both VS2017 and VS2019. I am officially stumped at what is going on.

Can anyone shed some light as to what I'm missing, so i can get either my win32 app, or freshly created WinRT project to build?

Comment: Do you have the Windows SDK installed somewhere? For example, on my PC all the winRT header files are located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\winrt` (10.0.19041.0 is the latest SDK version) and Visual Studio uses that.

Comment: @SimonMourier yes, but why is this not included as default on a new project? I would assume that the targeting of the project would take care of such things and a fresh project should be buildable from the get-go. I've never had to manually add a windows SDK to an include path, so this difference baffles me.

Comment: You don't need the Windows SDK to compile a C++/WinRT application. You do need to run the code generator (cppwinrt.exe) as part of your build. The project templates in the VSIX set this properly up for you. Trying to get that retrofitted to an existing Visual Studio project is fairly involved.

Comment: @IInspectable that may be what I'm missing. However i am a little confused. If the code generator is supposed to run on build with the templates, I'm confused as to why it's not building "fresh out the box" as it were. But you have given me a new line of investigation. I'll report back.

Comment: A clean C++/WinRT-based project is supposed to build out-of-the-box. Can you check whether you get a *Generated Files* folder in your source tree? That's where the code generator places header (and source) files. Also, what version of the VSIX are you using?

Comment: there is a bug in recent extension/nuget package https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/pull/781

Comment: @Force Gaia Have you fixed it? Can you describe the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has been fixed by https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/pull/781
Update your MSIX and NuGet packages

Comment: Despite this fix this can still happen. Example: A library project that uses WinRT and compiles just fine, but is then included by an executable project that does not compile. If you look at the evaluated values in the `Include Directories` property, you will find the `PreventSdkUapPropsAssignment` value. In this case you have to add the path manually as per Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message which I solved by adding

> %WindowsSdkDir%Include\WindowsTargetPlatformVersion\cppwinrt
> to the include path or by building the solution with just the include statements which also generates the headers and makes the winrt namespace work.

%WindowsSdkDir% can be obtained by opening a developer command prompt from the menu tools, command line and typing echo %WindowsSdkDir%,

the windowsTargetPlatformVersion can be  copied from configuration properties - Windows SDK Version

It is explained at this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/get-started#important-apis

Comment: `$(WinRT_IncludePath)\..\cppwinrt` worked for me and does not require the version to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a reference to windows .winmd installed somewhere

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd

or somewhere in vs directory by browsing in the reference window then

you can use "using Windows.Storage" that will include the necessary thing
I am not sure but I have a winform app in which I used this and it worked fine so maybe you can give it a shot

Comment: You don't need to add a reference to the system-provided .winmd files. They are in standard locations and the build system will automatically discover them. This holds true for libraries imported through NuGer as well.

Comment: Actually, this is the correct answer because of this issue https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/780

Comment: `using Windows.Storage` isn't valid C++. I'm not sure how you'd justify that as being *"correct"*.

Comment: @IInspectable true, but this is not an important part (I think this is just a typo). The important part is "manually add a dependency to Windows.winmd" because the main problem is that compiler cannot find header because they were not generated because of missing dependency.